# SQL Query to fetch results based on aggregate condition (sum of a column)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
Product   sl_no Wt_Kg
Prod-001    1   3.000
Prod-002    2   4.000
Prod-003    3   2.000
Prod-004    4   3.000
Prod-005    5   6.000
Prod-006    6   7.000
Prod-007    7   1.000
Prod-008    8   2.000
Prod-009    9   3.000
Prod-010    10  5.000
Prod-011    11  2.000
Prod-012    12  4.000
```

I need all records from this table staring from a sequence number and till a specified sum of weight in kgs is reached.
For example if I want to get all Products from serial no (Sl_no) 1 having sum of weight less than or equal to 25 kgs I should get the following result:

```
Product   sl_no Wt_Kg
Prod-001    1   3.000
Prod-002    2   4.000
Prod-003    3   2.000
Prod-004    4   3.000
Prod-005    5   6.000
Prod-006    6   7.000
```

In the next example, if I want all products staring from serial no 3 and weight less than or equal to 30kgs, I should get the following result:

```
Product   sl_no Wt_Kg
Prod-003    3   2.000
Prod-004    4   3.000
Prod-005    5   6.000
Prod-006    6   7.000
Prod-007    7   1.000
Prod-008    8   2.000
Prod-009    9   3.000
Prod-010    10  5.000
```

Please help me to achieve this. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Is serial number (sl_no) unique or there can be multiple records with this serial number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be more efficient. I started by creating a table called _test in my database matching your description. This solution takes advantage of the ability to increment a value in an `UPDATE` statment (http://haacked.com/archive/2004/02/28/sql-auto-increment.aspx). It stops incrementing after the target value is reached. Performance will be an issue if you have millions of products, but you could assume that you will reach your target weight within a certain number of products (based on average weight) and use `SET ROW_COUNT` to limit the initial number of records in the table variable.

```
DECLARE @Weight            REAL
DECLARE @SerialNumber      INT
DECLARE @MaxWeight         REAL

SET @Weight                = 0
SET @SerialNumber          = 3
SET @MaxWeight             = 30

DECLARE @Results TABLE
        (
        Product           CHAR(8),
        sl_no             INT,
        Wt_Kg             REAL,
        Total_Wt          REAL
        )

INSERT INTO
        @Results

(
        Product,
        sl_no,
        Wt_KG
)

SELECT
        Product,
        sl_no,
        Wt_KG

FROM
        _test

WHERE
        sl_no >= @SerialNumber  

ORDER BY
        sl_no


UPDATE
        @Results

SET 
        @Weight = Total_Wt = Wt_Kg + @Weight

WHERE 
        @Weight <= @MaxWeight


SELECT
        *

FROM 
        @Results

WHERE 
        Total_Wt <= @MaxWeight
```

Results are:

```
Product  sl_no       Wt_Kg         Total_Wt
-------- ----------- ------------- -------------
Prod-003 3           2             2
Prod-004 4           3             5
Prod-005 5           6             11
Prod-006 6           7             18
Prod-007 7           1             19
Prod-008 8           2             21
Prod-009 9           3             24
Prod-010 10          5             29
```

Comment: Hi Keith, can this entire thing be done using a view? If yes, kindly write the view.

Comment: No, this would have to be in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @total decimal(9,3), @sl_no int
select @total = 25.000, @sl_no = 0 -- first case
--select @total = 30.000, @sl_no = 3 -- second case

;with tab (Product, sl_no, Wt_Kg) as (
    select 'Prod-001', 1, 3.000 union all
    select 'Prod-002', 2, 4.000 union all
    select 'Prod-003', 3, 2.000 union all
    select 'Prod-004', 4, 3.000 union all
    select 'Prod-005', 5, 6.000 union all
    select 'Prod-006', 6, 7.000 union all
    select 'Prod-007', 7, 1.000 union all
    select 'Prod-008', 8, 2.000 union all
    select 'Prod-009', 9, 3.000 union all
    select 'Prod-010', 10, 5.000 union all
    select 'Prod-011', 11, 2.000 union all
    select 'Prod-012', 12, 4.000
)
select t3.*
from tab t3
join (
    select t1.product, t1.sl_no, sum(t2.Wt_Kg) as total
    from tab t1
    join tab t2 on t1.sl_no >= t2.sl_no
    where t2.sl_no >= @sl_no
    group by t1.product, t1.sl_no
) t on t.product = t3.product and t.sl_no = t3.sl_no
where t.total <= @total
```

**Added**: grouping and joining by `sl_no` (just in case when `product` is not unique)

Results are, first case:

```
Product sl_no   Wt_Kg
Prod-001    1   3.000
Prod-002    2   4.000
Prod-003    3   2.000
Prod-004    4   3.000
Prod-005    5   6.000
Prod-006    6   7.000
```

second case:

```
Product sl_no   Wt_Kg
Prod-003    3   2.000
Prod-004    4   3.000
Prod-005    5   6.000
Prod-006    6   7.000
Prod-007    7   1.000
Prod-008    8   2.000
Prod-009    9   3.000
Prod-010    10  5.000
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
declare @total decimal(9,3), @sl_no int
select @total = 25.000, @sl_no = 1 -- first case


select * from Tab where sl_no<=
(
    select MAX(sl_no3) from (
        select t3.sl_no sl_no3, sum(t3.Wt_kg) Wt_kg3 from (
            select t1.sl_no sl_no, t2.Wt_Kg as Wt_kg from Tab t1, Tab t2 where t1.sl_no>=t2.sl_no and t2.sl_no >=@sl_no
        ) t3 group by t3.sl_no having SUM(t3.Wt_kg) <= @total
    ) t4
) and sl_no>=$sl_no
```

Answer (score 0):

**If serial number is unique:**

First example:

```
select *
from tableName
where sl_no >= 1
and Wt_Kg <= 25
```

Second example:

```
select *
from tableName
where sl_no >= 3
and Wt_Kg <= 30
```

**If serial number is not unique:**

```
select Product, sl_no, Sum(Wt_Kg)
from tableName
where Wt_Kg <= 25
group by Product, sl_no
```

**EDIT**:

If you want to filter results by summed value you could try this:

```
select Product, sl_no, Sum(Wt_Kg)
from tableName
group by Product, sl_no
having (Sum(Wt_Kg) <= 25)
```

Keep in mind that if Product OR sl_no are unique than Sum() doesn't make sense becuse aggregate is used for records that share certain values.

Comment: Grouping in your edited part will not change anything. There is no more than one row wit specific `sl_no` so for each `sl_no` sum returns just value of `Wt_Kg`.

Comment: Last query is also under title "If serial number is not unique:"

Comment: I'm confused now, so which query returns expected result (1st or 2nd) for sample data from question?

Comment: If Nagesh's table looks exactly like in his example and he literally wants exact same results as he stated in his question than First Example query is for his first case and Second example query is for his second case.

Comment: Your 1st example returns all rows and 2nd returns all rows without those with `sl_no` equals 1 or 2. I think that question is about `sum` of `Wt_Kg`s lower or equal 25/30 and not `Wt_Kg` value itself.

Comment: Oh, I see your point. Actually, now I see that I didn't understand the question at all, I thought he was asking something else. Unfortunately, I don't have answer to Nagesh's question, but it's definitely interesting

Comment: My product table has many other attributes. The search condition is based on many other filters, which I have not mentioned here.